# Can I specify multiple bibliography (BibTeX) files in Pandoc Metadata?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

Often, scientific journal websites and other sources offer downloadable `*.bib` files for referring to individual articles. If I use these, I like to keep them as they are instead of merging them into a single file. On the command line, several files can be specified by passing the `--bibliography` option multiple times. Can I also list multiple files in the YAML metadata inside the `*.md` document itself?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use biblatex for a citation formatter, you can set up multiple bib files in your YAML front matter:

```
---
bibliography:
- mybib1.bib
- mybib2.bib
---
```

You'll need to compile with:

```
pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.pdf --biblatex
```

This works because the latex templates contains a `$for(bibliography)$` loop:

```
$if(biblatex)$
\usepackage[$if(biblio-style)$style=$biblio-style$,$endif$$for(biblatexoptions)$$biblatexoptions$$sep$,$
$for(bibliography)$
\addbibresource{$bibliography$}
$endfor$
$endif$
```

Comment: Can I use biblatex regardless of the output format? I'd like to be able to produce both PDFs and Word Documents (`*.docx`).

Comment: No, you have to use pandoc-citeproc for output format other than latex/beamer.

Comment: @tarleb Can you make an answer of the information in your comment?

Answer (score 3):

Bibliographies can be specified in document metadata, i.e. via for Markdown in YAML blocks:

```
---
bibliography:
- one.bib
- two.bib
- three.bib
---
```

This only works if `pandoc-citeproc` is invoked as a filter by passing `--filter=pandoc-citeproc` on the command line. E.g.,

```
$ pandoc --filter=pandoc-citeproc --from=markdown --to=latex my-file.md
```

To understand why, we must take a step back and look at the way pandoc handles citations.  Usually, i.e. if no alternative citation method has been requested via `--natbib` or `--biblatex`, pandoc uses pandoc-citeproc to handle citations, ensuring comparable citation handling across different formats. `pandoc-citeproc` works as a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html): the program receives the full document in pandoc's JSON format and performs the following steps:

1. get the bibliography file(s) from the *bibliography* metadata field;
2. collect all citations in the document;
3. create a bibliography and insert appropriate text in the document;
4. encode the resulting document to JSON again and write to stdout.

Pandoc will then continue its work using the modified document.

The `bibliography` field can be set either via the command line or in the document itself. The only difference between using command line options or YAML metadata is that pandoc invokes `pandoc-citeproc` automatically if the bibliography is given as a CLI parameter. Since we don't want this, we need to tell pandoc explicitly that the pandoc-citeproc filter must be called.